# Why am I getting packet loss when pinging raspberry pis on subnet?

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, subnet, hub, packet-loss

I have three raspberry pis connected together on a subnet via a hub. I've given them all static IPs and I'm using one main Pi to ping the other two Pis.

Here is my setup: 
[image: pic of setup]

Once the main Pi starts pinging another Pi, each ping returns back totally fine. But when I initially start the ping it can take around 5 seconds to receive its first response back. This leads to 30%+ in packet loss or so and makes it so that when I run scripts they often fail at transmitting messages due to timeouts trying to connect.

Here is a photo of the packet loss when pinging one pi then the other:

[image]

I'm very new to networking so please let me know what information I can provide to better diagnose the issue.

I've tried replacing the raspberry pis, the ethernet cables, and the hub but no luck as of yet. I'm wondering if there is some limitation on the Pis Im unaware of or if this might be a faulty hardware issue with my hub supplier.

EDIT: I ran `IP neighbor show` with the following results

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip neighbor show
192.168.2.1 dev wlan0 lladdr 40:c7:29:4e:4d:f8 STALE
192.168.3.32 dev enxb827eb9c0ecf lladdr 00:e0:4c:53:44:58 STALE
192.168.2.131 dev wlan0 lladdr 02:0f:b5:87:93:39 REACHABLE
192.168.3.37 dev enxb827eb9c0ecf lladdr 00:e0:4c:53:44:58 STALE
```

The reason it shows two different networks is that I'm connected to the internet over wifi on the `192.168.2` network. And I'm connected via ethernet to the other 2 pis over `192.168.3`. Both Pis IPs can be seen there as `.3.37` and `.3.32` respectively.

EDIT2: I noticed from playing around with `IP neighbor show` that if I ping a pi then run `IP neighbor show` it says `REACHABLE` next to that pi. But then if I ping the other Pi then the first Pi I pinged will display `STALE` and the new one will be `REACHABLE` this happens each time I ping the other Pi.

Comment: Why are you using a hub and not an Ethernet switch?

Comment: Because hubs are cheaper :P. I bought a switch today to try it and had the exact same issue

Comment: According to the symptoms you experience, you actually have a switch instead of a hub, as a switch keeps a mapping of mac address to port, but an hub broadcasts all traffic. You wouldn't get mac address conflict packet loss if it was a hub.

Comment: @Ferrybig you're the man. Thanks for checking both my posts haha cheers

Comment: I didn't even realise I checked both you posts... It's just that you say that, I just say an question with an interesting title in the related section

Comment: Both your comments taught me something I didn't know, so thanks anyways man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that both of your Raspberry Pi's have the same MAC address. We can see this from the output of `ip neighbor show` where both `3.32` and `3.37` have the MAC address `00:e0:4c:53:44:58`. Not only will you experience what you've already been experiencing with the pings, but any communication between your main Pi and both other Pi's simultaneously will also be problematic.

This shouldn't be the case since MAC addresses are supposed to be globally unique, but alas, here we are. To fix this, you'll need to find a way to change the MAC address by hand. [This post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=159433) from the Pi forums seems to suggest a way to do this:

> Essentially, create a file "/etc/systemd/network/00-default.link" with contents:
>
> ```
> [Match]
> MACAddress=current MAC address
>
> [Link]
> MACAddress=new MAC address
> ```
>
> Then sudo ifdown and ifup the interface and it should have its new MAC address, and the change will persist through reboots.

MAC address numbers are 12 hexadecimal characters (0-9, a-f). They're usually separated every two characters by colons or dashes, but those are not actually part of the address. For example:

```
01:23:45:ab:cd:ef
```

Yes, just use some random characters. We just need something unique.

Comment: Dude, I'm trying that now but that completely makes sense. Thank you so so so much. I've been trying to fix this for 36 hours. I absolutely cannot thank you enough

Comment: I do need it to survive reboots but I remember reading somewhere that `/etc/nework/interfaces` is outdated and to make all changes through `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` now, I assume that should still hold true with regard to MAC address changes.  Also what is the format to MAC address numbers, I see that some have letters in them - do I just pick letters/numbers at random in the format xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx?

Comment: I've updated the method for changing the MAC address and expanded a bit on MAC address formatting.

Comment: this method randomly stopped working for me today - I've made a new post about it [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1366349/why-isnt-my-forced-mac-address-change-working-raspberry-pi)

Answer (score 1):

When you start the initial ping, issue the following command:

`ip neighbor show`

This will show the ARP cache and give a hint if ARP resulution has taken place or not.

Just edit your question and put the output there and add also the IPs of the target RasPIs.

Comment: I ran the command and updated my post